Calling CDK programmatically from within library
I want to create a Typescript library that completely encapsulates CDK.  So if I have a typescript program that imports this library and calls create_chatbot() it stands up a stack with all the resources.  This means all the CDK files are published with the library so the calling program doesn't have to care or even know about CDK files.
I thought this was possible with "@aws-cdk/cli-lib-alpha" and it was, or rather, my first simple library with code like below worked
import { AwsCdkCli } from '@aws-cdk/cli-lib-alpha';

function create_chatbot() {
  const rootdir = path.dirname(__dirname)
  const cli = AwsCdkCli.fromCdkAppDirectory(rootdir);
  cli.deploy({
    stacks: ["chatbot"],
  })
}
exports.create_chatbot = create_chatbot


But when I tried to augment that and put code in that used other node libraries like "fs", the import failed.

Cannot find module 'fs' or its corresponding type declarations.

I presume because all cli-lib-alpha does is run a subprocess that runs CDK, and the subprocess's working directory is node_modules/mychatbotlibrary so it doesn't see all the other node_modules.
Is there a way to get cli-lib-alpha to work in this paradigm?  Or is there another way to encapsulate CDK within a typescript library? Or any other type of library for that matter?
